# How can I customize the error message while using JSON schema that has key as regex (using patternProperties)?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have the following JSON schema:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "patternProperties": {
    "^[a-zA-Z]+$": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "patternProperties": {
        "^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$": {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "properties": {
            "common": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "The common version for the object."
            }
          },
          "required": ["common"],
          "patternProperties": {
            "^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "A specific version for the object."
            }
          },
          "description": "An object within the language."
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This schema should validate the following structure:

```
{
    "Language":{
        "obj1":{
            "common":"str1",
            "version1":"str123"
        },
        "obj2":{
            "common":"str2",
            "version2":"str567"
        }
    }
}
```

note: each object in a language must have a common version, any other version is optional. Language keys, object keys and version keys are validate as regular expression as you can see in the schema above.

I tried to validate this JSON as an example:

```
{
    "English":{
        "obj1":{
            "version1":"123"
        },
        "obj2":{
            "common":"test",
            "version2*":"123"
        }
    }
}
```

As a result, I got a JSON result. For the missing common version at obj1 I got a relevant error:

```
 {
      "valid": false,
      "evaluationPath": "/patternProperties/^[a-zA-Z]+$/patternProperties/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$",
      "schemaLocation": "https://json-everything.net/392680f067#/patternProperties/^[a-zA-Z]+$/patternProperties/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$",
      "instanceLocation": "/English/obj1",
      "errors": {
        "required": "Required properties [\"common\"] were not present"
      }
    }
```

but for the * character at the second version in obj2 I got:

```
  {
      "valid": false,
      "evaluationPath": "/patternProperties/^[a-zA-Z]+$/patternProperties/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$/additionalProperties",
      "schemaLocation": "https://json-everything.net/392680f067#/patternProperties/^[a-zA-Z]+$/patternProperties/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$/additionalProperties",
      "instanceLocation": "/English/obj2/version2*",
      "errors": {
       "": "All values fail against the false schema"
      }
    }
```

There is any way to change the error message and put a key to it so it will be not empty?

Thanks!

I tried to pass an object "message":{"":"pattern is not valid"}, but it doesn't work.
I expect to modify the error message as "The pattern is not valid" for each key that has regex.